# Apache 2.4.x Override Charset after update to ubuntu 15.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, character-encoding, apache2

Disabling in `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` by adding '#' befor it in

```
 conf-enabled/charset.conf
```

Nothing change...

**UPDATE:**

```
      grep -i 'UTF-8' /etc/apache2/* -R
```

Our problem is in file `mods-enabled/autoindex.conf`
at line=8

and...

```
  service apache2 restart
```

but apache2 still override charset

**UPDATE 2**

`phpinfo()`
give interesting tip
`default_charset = UTF-8`

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

in `php.ini`

set
`default_charset = ""`

This works.

Comment: I've been struggling with this issue for two weeks now! And the solution is so simple.